# SVG click using d3 freezes IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I have a small angular app that stores a variable called start in the scope - it displays a play or pause svg icon that is clickable.

I use d3 to attach the click event and store what the next action is using d3.selection.datum

This works in all browsers except IE 11. You can click it the first time to change scope.start to be true and then it freezes.

Plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/8bER7e0z69KAzEFFm2jN?p=preview

Help appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Colleague wrote a workaround to just do the old fashioned show/hide play/pause icon instead of trying to replace the svg icon.
Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mjDRu4NCAvqpm2gJvKbv?p=preview